Protocol to transform _Staphylococcus aureus_
I'm working on transforming Staphylococcus aureus and I'm
totally lost on bypassing the RM systems. I have a plasmid already constructed, but I think I want to pass it through DC10B E. coli so that it loses its methylation and is staph-compatible.
Let me know if this is a feasible plan. Are there any known protocols for this task?

I'm not particularly familiar with S. aureus genetic transformation protocols, but it looks like a quick search reveals some articles related to the topic.
